# phpstorm 8 find in files and folders without a project

Tags: find, phpstorm

I think this is quite a simple operation but I cant make it work. All i want to do is find a string occurrence in a directory of project files.

In Dreamweaver and Notepad++ this is easy and works, when I do it in Phpstorm no results are found and i get a message saying something like:

> No occurrences of 'STRING' found in Directory c:\projects\newProject\website 5 usages are out of scope 'Project and Libraries'

I want the 5 usages returned how do i do that?
[image: search setup]

[image: search message]

Comment: 1) What do you mean by *"without a project"*? 2) Screenshots please (your search settings etc) -- not everybody has their remote-mind-reading helmets available and working today.

Comment: Yes sorry for not including the screen shot. I have edited above. 

I mean "without a project" I just want to search through files without having to link them to a phpstorm project.

Comment: Is `c:\projects\newProject\website` path is the project root? If so -- try "Whole project" option instead. Another thought: maybe those occurrences are in files/folders that are excluded from the project? If yes -- then IDE should not be finding them. You can also try "File | Invalidate caches" -- may help in certain situations (sooty, cannot be more specific since I do not have any info about your project structure).

Comment: I tried whole project i get No occurrences of 'path' found in Project. I am trying to search files that were created outside of Storm. So are not a "project" they are files in a ./dir like: index.php, about.php, hello.php

Comment: IDE says that those files are not in "Project and Libraries" scope. So where they are? I'm sorry, but without having some details I cannot give you any solid advices. So far it looks similar to https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-130076 or https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WI-24130

Comment: Thank you @LazyOne for your help. It does seem like a bug. the first link you mentioned is exactly my problem. I hope they fix it soon. Again thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This problem is fixed in the new PHPstorm 9

Comment: Still see this problem in PHPstorm 11.0.3

Answer (score 0):

I dont know why but you need to do RE RUN CTRL+F5 after your search
It works only if files are in other project.